# Transpose elements in a column into multiple columns by group in R

Tags: r, vector, transpose

Given the data

```
test_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
test_values <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
test_df <- data.frame(test_id, test_values)
test_df

  test_id       test_values
        1           1
        1           2
        1           3
        2           4
        2           5
        2           6
```

I would like to transpose the value column into a row

```
test_df$x1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4)
test_df$x2 <- c(2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5)
test_df$x3 <- c(3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6)
test_df

 test_id        test_values   x1           x2           x3
        1           1          1            2            3
        1           2          1            2            3
        1           3          1            2            3
        2           4          4            5            6
        2           5          4            5            6
        2           6          4            5            6
```

I originally had in mind something like

```
test_df <- test_df %>%
  group_by(test_id) %>%
  mutate(X = t(test_values))%>%
  ungroup()
```

but this does not allow splitting the column into multiple entries - x1,x2,x3. Any suggestion about how to tackle the issue would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with pivots and joins:

```
test_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
test_values <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
test_df <- data.frame(test_id, test_values)

test_df %>% 
  group_by(test_id) %>% 
  mutate(var = seq_along(test_values)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from="test_values", names_from="var", names_prefix="x") %>% 
  left_join(test_df %>% dplyr::select(test_id, test_values), .)
# Joining, by = "test_id"
#   test_id test_values x1 x2 x3
# 1       1           1  1  2  3
# 2       1           2  1  2  3
# 3       1           3  1  2  3
# 4       2           4  4  5  6
# 5       2           5  4  5  6
# 6       2           6  4  5  6
```

Or, if you only wanted one row per `test_id` you could just remove the last line:

```
test_df %>% 
  group_by(test_id) %>% 
  mutate(var = seq_along(test_values)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from="test_values", names_from="var", names_prefix="x") 
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Groups:   test_id [2]
#   test_id    x1    x2    x3
#      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1       1     1     2     3
# 2       2     4     5     6
```

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful code. Although It works smoothly with the mock dataset above, it orders values across a diagonal rather then pooling them by row in my real dataset. I don't understand what's the difference.

Comment: Can you post some of the real data?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to disclose them. But the logic is the same as the data above, with the only difference that they involve 40 IDs instead of 2, and 10 binary values for each ID instead of 3 integer values. One solution may be to fill all NAs with the value above / below in the relevant column per each ID. Thank you however for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
setDT(test_df)[,c(.(test_values = test_values),data.frame(outer(rep(1,.N),test_values))),test_id]
```

where `outer` is applied to make the transpose, such that

```
   test_id test_values X1 X2 X3
1:       1           1  1  2  3
2:       1           2  1  2  3
3:       1           3  1  2  3
4:       2           4  4  5  6
5:       2           5  4  5  6
6:       2           6  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `unnest_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test_df %>%
    group_by(test_id) %>%  
    transmute(col1 = list(test_values)) %>%
    unnest_wider(c(col1)) %>% 
    rename_at(vars(starts_with("...")),
       ~ str_replace(., fixed("..."), "x")) %>% 
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  test_id    x1    x2    x3
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1       1     1     2     3
#2       1     1     2     3
#3       1     1     2     3
#4       2     4     5     6
#5       2     4     5     6
#6       2     4     5     6
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
test_df[paste0('x', 1:3)] <-  do.call(rbind, with(test_df, 
          split(test_values, test_id)))[test_df$test_id,]
```